# How to view FPDF pdf via http response in Django?

Tags: django, fpdf

Hello I'm trying to view pdf on browser new tab via FPDF. getting error
here my code.

```
class PDFWithHeaderFooter(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        # Add your header content here
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Your Header Text', 0, 1, 'C')

    def footer(self):
        # Add your footer content here
        self.set_y(-15)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page %s' % self.page_no(), 0, 0, 'C')


@login_required(login_url='/')
def Print_Quote(request, pk):
    id = Quote.objects.get(id = pk)
    term = id.terms.all()
    quote_item = Quote_item.objects.filter( quotes = id )
    sub_total = quote_item.aggregate(Sum('sub_total'))
    gst_total = quote_item.aggregate(Sum('gst_total'))
    total = quote_item.aggregate(Sum('total'))

    pdf = FPDF(format='letter')
    pdf = PDFWithHeaderFooter()
    # Add content to the PDF
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello, World!')
     # Save the PDF to a HttpResponse
    pdf.output()
    
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

I'm view pdf on new tab but it's show me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not know what your error is. But try to return the pdf file via binary stream *(irrelevant part skipped)*:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse

    ...
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello, World!')
    file_stream = io.BytesIO(pdf.output())
    return FileResponse(file_stream, as_attachment=False, filename="test.pdf")
```